# Is there any way to increase the pagespeed-insight score for pages which have Google Adsense on?

Tags: pagespeed-insights

Say I have a page with Google Ads on it.

I have optimized everything I can and got a very high score without the ads.

However, if I active the ads, the score would be very low.

Is there any way that I can increase the pagespeed-insight score with the ads on?

I have tried to postpone the show of the ads but it's not very user-friendly.

Comment: use a different ad network? Sadly other than preconnecting to required domains and because of the fact you can't delay the ads due to user experience, you are reliant on the ad network's code and so you cannot do much.

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion you can use lazyload to handle pagespeed problems on adsense

The following is the script that I often use to deal with this problem, put it in the  tag

`<script type='text/javascript'>
var lazyadsense=!1;window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){(0!=document.documentElement.scrollTop&&!1===lazyadsense||0!=document.body.scrollTop&&!1===lazyadsense)&&(!function(){var e=document.createElement("script");e.type="text/javascript",e.async=!0,e.src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js";var a=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.parentNode.insertBefore(e,a)}(),lazyadsense=!0)},!0);
//]]>
</script>`

make sure you has been delete this code
`<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>`

Comment: +1, By the way I think it's a good idea to have a named function and remove the document scroll event listener after appending the script to the end of the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same code with options {passive: true, once: true}. So, no need to remove scroll events.